# Call an EL function with a Scriptlet variable

Tags: jsp, el, scriptlet

I seem to be having a weird issue where I can not pass a Scriptlet variable to an EL function call. It will all run properly but it sends a null value instead of what I set in the jsp... I feel like I am missing something very basic here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<%@ Sudo / All other tag's required.... %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn_" uri="/WEB-INF/tags.tld" %>

    <script>
    
<%  LinkedList<MyBean> mb = (LinkedList<MyBean>)request.getAttribute("mBean"); %>
<%  String f="first"; %>
    </script>

</head>

        <td>${fn_:getMyBean(mb,f)}</td>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib
    xsi:schemaLocation= "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    version="2.1">
     
     <tlib-version>1.1.2</tlib-version>
     <uri>http://some.thing/mine</uri>
     
     <function>
     <name>getMyBean</name>
     <function-class>com.glass.MyBean</function-class>
     <function-signature>java.lang.String getMyBean(java.util.List, java.lang.String)</function-signature>
     
     </function>
     
     
</taglib>
```

```
package com.glass;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyBean{

    
    public static String getMyBean( List<MyBean>cb, String st) {
        return "Hit! "+ st;
    }
```

The output will give this:

> Hit!

And does not return the string value. When I run the debugger I can see that the string value is null. I also tested below if I just try to get the String value like : `<%=f%>`
It does properly show me the value.

How do I properly use a String value in a EL Function call?

Comment: Did you try `<c:set var="f" scope="request" value="first"/>` and then `${fn_:getMyBean(mb,f)}`?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Yes doing it that way did allow me to pass in the string, thank you. I had tried something similar but was doing it incorrect Like this:
<c:set var="name" scope="scope" value=${=f}>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the value of `f` as follows:

```
<c:set var="f" scope="request" value="first"/>
```

and then use it as follows:

```
${fn_:getMyBean(mb,f)}
```